# Tricky parts in the song 'J'ai cherché' by Amir

Tags: paroles-de-chanson

(It's my very first question here, and I've only started learning French.)

> J’ai cherché un sens à mon existence
>     J’y ai laissé mon innocence

I have looked for a meaning to my existence
I have left my innocence ...

1. What does 'y' refer to? It's not just some indefinite 'there', is it?

> J’ai fini le cœur sans défense

I have finished with the unprotected heart

2. Am I correct in inserting the preposition 'with', rather than translating it along the line of 'I have terminated the unprotected heart'?

> J’ai bu tant de liqueurs amères
>   Que j’en ai les lèvres de pierre

I have drunk so many bitter liqueurs that I have lips of stone ...

3. I would guess that 'en' means 'because of them [those bitter liqueurs]'. If that's the case, what's the logic behind it?

> Au gré de nos blessures et de nos désinvoltures
>   C’est quand on n’y croit plus du tout
>   Qu’on trouve un paradis perdu en nous

Along the course of injuries and ..., it's when we don't believe in ... anymore that we find a lost paradise in ourselves.

4. Again, I don't know what 'y' refers to. And the meaning of 'désinvolture' a dictionary has given me (offhand manner, flippancy) doesn't seem to fit. And am I right in translating 'au gré de' as 'along the course of'?

Comment: 1. “Y” -> “in doing so”; 
2. “fini” -> “ended up”; 
3. “En” refers to the drinking; 
4. “y” -> “in it”. Usually words like "y", "en" refers to previous statements.

Comment: For 3, I think "I have drunk so many bitter liqueurs that my lips turned to stone" is a translation closer to the original meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation you have done doesn't fit the meaning of this text.

1. I'll try to explain the y. It is used to replace a word, previously used after a preposition.

Here the **y** is supposed to refer to the existence. **BUT** I think the author means that, in his quest to search for a meaning to his existence, he lost his innocence. Which means the **y** refer to the whole sentence, and not only to existence.

For example, "je vais au cinéma...tu y va aussi ?" => I'm going to the cinema.. are you going too ? the **y** is used to refer to **cinema**

The other preposition you might want to know about is **en**. It's the same, but for direct object.

Example : "j'ai mangé une pomme, j'en veux encore une" => I've eaten an apple, I would like another one.The **en** is used to refer to **apple**.

2. About the second sentence, I don't think you understood it right

J'ai fini le coeur sans défense => I ended up with a defenless hearth.

Ask if you don't understand.

3. I explained you earlier about the "en" ^^
4. Same here, try to guess what the "y" is referring too ;) désinvolture means offhandedness, if you understand the meaning of it in the sentence.

Comment: Thank you. (3) So, 'en' refers to the direct object in the preceding clause, which is 'tant de liqueurs améres. But then a preposition seems to be needed here: 'I have lips of stone [...] so many bitter liqueurs'. That's why I guess 'because of'. (4) If 'y' refers to 'au gré de nos ...', then: 'Along the course of injuries and offhandedness, it's when we don't believe in them that we find a lost paradise in ourselves'. Is this correct?

Comment: (3) yes that's it. (4) No, that's why I told you to guess ahah => the translation is "it's when we don't believe in it anymore", the it refer to the search of the meaning of the existence ^^

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to answer your questions :)

1. **y** refers to his search for a meaning to his existence. Yes, it's an indefinite there, even though it's not really a place, we use it like this.
2. Yes you're correct, though I would have said *an/my* instead of *the*.
3. **En** has the meaning of **by doing so**. The sentence is a metaphore, though I'm not sure I understand it, maybe he can't feel anything with his lips anymore ?

**En** is a really difficult word to grasp the meaning of. It's usually used to avoid repetitions in a sentence. It replaces what we're talking about.

> Tu vois ces pommes ? Je vais **en** faire de la confiture. | *See those apples ? I'm gonna turn them into jam.*
>
> Tu te rappelles de son numéro ? Non je ne m'**en** rappelle plus. | *Do you remember his number ? No, I don't remember it.*
>
> Je ne sais rien. Question ? Je n'**en** sais rien. / *I don't know anything. I don't know anything about this.*
>
> Je ne mange pas. Je n'**en** mange pas. / *I don't eat. I don't eat that (thing we're talking about).*
>
> Des lapins ? J'en ai vu plein hier ! / Rabbits ? I saw a lot of them yesterday !

You can add **en** before almost any verbe.

4. *Désinvolture* refers to being bolt. **Y** refers to the thing he stops believing **in** (the lost paradise in ourselves).

   > Je crois **en** Dieu. Je n'**y** crois pas.

/!\ This is not the same meaning of en, here it means in.